# Jenkins URL with own domain

Tags: iis, jenkins, continuous-integration, windows-server-2008

I have installed Jenkins Continues Integration system on my windows server successfully and it works without any errors. But I was unable to get `Jenkins URL` working with my host domain. The default Jenkins address which is `http://localhost:8080` works well. My domain/server name is `projectdev` so I want to give Jenkins the `http://projectdev/jenkins` URL so that other developers in my network will be able to access Jenkins dashboard easily.

Although I added `http://projectdev/jenkins` as the Jenkins URL from the Jenkins configuration sections, it doesn’t work. I can’t access it from other computers in my network. But when I use `http://localhost:8080` I can access the dashboard directly.

I also tried to add Jenkins as a web application on `IIS` and give it the address I want.  But I don’t know what to provide as the physical path of Jenkins as it was installed using Jenkins.jar file.
It would be really great if someone can help me to get this done as I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure IIS to re-route requests to {domain}/jenkins to {domain}:8080/jenkins

check the info on:

http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/microsoft-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-7/setting-up-a-server-farm-with-the-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis

Comment: An easier (similar) method https://blog.dangl.me/archive/installing-and-configuring-jenkins-on-windows-server-with-iis/

Answer (score 1):

Try this address: `http://projectdev:8080/jenkins` If you type without 8080 port , the port will be 80 by default.

Comment: Thank you! but I want it to be {hostname}/jenkins, because that's the formation I have used for application I have hosted in my server.

Comment: If your host is just for Jenkins, take the 80 port for your jenkins.

Comment: does that mean it is impossible to have such a url with 8080 port number? i already have configured another application with 80 port. so i can't use that.